# Is there a way to implement a Redo() function for TextBox? C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I'm very confused with the `TextBox`, as I'm used to working with `RichTextBox` (I decided to switch because it seems faster..) and I have a problem:

The `TextBox`, unlike `RichTextBox`, doesn't seem to have a `textBox.Redo();` function-- at all. Is there a way to implement a `.Redo()` function for `TextBox`, or is it impossible?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: [EM_UNDO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-undo) message + [EM_CANUNDO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-canundo) message etc.

Comment: But what does that have to do with _Redo_? Sorry if I'm coming across as rude :)

Comment: So you can read about it. Which will probably take you to [EM_REDO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-redo) and you can see what it applies to and a few suggestion about the Undo / Redo queues (e.g., if you can Undo() you can also Redo(), you need to cache the last operation yourself, since the TextBox Control doesn't support an `EM_REDO` message).

Comment: How would I cache the last operation? I'm reading articles regarding EM_REDO but none of them involve caching the last operation, or even involve the TextBox-- I'm missing something here, I can feel it..

Comment: [Memento Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern). You usually start from something like this: [IEditableObject Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject). This defines the base implementation. (The RichTextBox Control is always available - also commercial products, but you could try the [Fast Colored TextBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting-2): you can find different implementations of it and questions here)

Comment: Is the `RichTextBox` a more optimal choice than the `TextBox`?

Comment: *Optimal* for what use cases? -- Try that open source Control, it's based on the standard RichTextBox.

Comment: In terms of speed, would the `RichTextBox` be better than `TextBox`? I'm currently trying the open source Control you linked :)

Comment: Get it from GitHub: [FastColoredTextBox](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox). Note that you can add it to a Project as a [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FCTB/)

Comment: Is the Fast Colored TextBox allowed for commercial use? I'm planning on writing my own, but I'd like to know :)

Comment: The Package has a License note

Comment: The license is a bit unclear, but I'll have to write my own control anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [TextBoxBase.Undo()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.windows.forms/R/ec0b9d738237501b.html), a call is made via `SendMessage` with `EM_UNDO` as the message.

In [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-undo#remarks) for `EM_UNDO` we can see the following:

> **Edit controls and Rich Edit 1.0:** An undo operation can also be undone. For example, you can restore deleted text with the first EM_UNDO message, and remove the text again with a second EM_UNDO message as long as there is no intervening edit operation.

So calling `Undo()` again will redo.

Comment: So, for the `Redo` button, I would just put `textBox.Undo();`? Like the actual `Undo` button? Or am I missing something :D

Comment: Indeed, exactly that. You can actually see this working in Notepad.exe, which uses an Edit control internally